Include the remote hostname on each line of output from Invoke-Command cmd.exe
I have some code like this:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers {
    cmd.exe /c ThirdPartyScript.bat
}

How do I include the remote hostname on each line of output?

Invoke-Command { ... } |Select-Object PSComputerName,@{Name='Output';Expression={"$_"}}

Thanks, this works great apart from ERROR: lines.. any way to handle those?

Depends a bit on how you want to handle them - try merging the error stream into stdout on the remote and see if that result works for you: cmd /c ... 2>&1

or invoke-command $servers { [pscustomobject]@{result = thirdpartyscript.bat 2>&1} }  You can test elevated on localhost.

A powershell script could be stored locally.  invoke-command $servers script.ps1.
